# How to execute all test case in the “spring-boot” project with gradle?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

spring-boot migrated from maven to gradle  since 2.3.0.M1, so the question is tagged with **gradle**. [link](https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/08/migrating-spring-boot-s-build-to-gradle)

**What I want to do?**
We known, **spring-boot-dependencies** project is managing lots of jar's version and works well, that's so  great! We plan to use spring-boot-dependencies as a basic to manage jar's version in my company. sometimes we need to upgrade some of the jar in spring-boot-dependencies because of vulnerabilities, and this may cause **version mismatch** between jars.

I have noticed that, there is about 10*000 tests case in springboot project:
[image]

So I'd like to modify some jar's version in the spring-boot-dependencies project, and then run all test of spring-boot projects, to help me analyse is there any **version mismatch**。

**What I did?**

1. clone the latest code from github:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot.git
2. run `.\gradlew.bat build`(work on windows) in the spring-boot project root directory.
3. it seems only a few tests get executed:
   [image]

So, my question is how can I execute all **test case** in spring-boot project?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

the path `buildSrc/` is for the gradle custom plugin code. You are therefore looking at the build tool test results.

your main code results will be under `build/reports/...` folder (of each module)

Comment: Thanks!  There is only one file in `build` floder: `build-scan-uri.txt`, with content: `build scan not generated`. Maybe failed test in `buildSrc` caused this.

Comment: Great! After I removed failed tests in buildSrc, a lot of tests in other directory get executed with `gradle build` command。But tests under `spring-boot-tests` dosen't get excuted, trying to figure out...